# Single brushed DC motor driver not working when using step up voltage regulator

Tags: dc-motor, step-up, motordriver

I'm using [this](https://www.pololu.com/product/2997) Pololu single brushed drive to control a DC motor. Its voltage working range is from 4.5 to 28V and it works fine when I supply it with two 18650 batteries in series.

I want to make it to work with a single 18650 battery and since the maximum voltage would be 4.2V, I got [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07MKGN6M4/ref=pe_3187911_185740111_TE_item) stepup to boost the voltage. However, it doesn't work at all. I re-checked several times and as soon as I supply the drive with the boost converter it stops working.

I'm quite new in the field of electronics and so not really sure if this normal or not. Is it possible to use stepup converters with drives such as the one I'm using, or this is something that will never work?

**EDIT: add a schematic**

[image]

Comment: Start current at higher voltage may be exceeding the converters current limit. IF there is a current limit (apparently not), set it to max.  Try putting a larger cap across Vout - MAY need a small series output resistor before cap to limit Iinrush. || Try adjusting Vout to slightly above Vin without motor and then add motor. Try that at increasing voltages. | | Can you try initially it with converter and motor only and no controller. || Report back.

Comment: Thanks. Already tried converter with motor only and it works fine. How large the capacitor? And put it in parallel with the ground?

Comment: Cap Vout to ground. |BUT maybe not - you need to describe the real problem which appears now to NOT be the converter but the controller. You do not say what Vout is when you try - is this the case with all Vouts? Do you set controller speed to zero to start? Do uou ....? -> Tell us as much as you can re what you are doing and trying. Try a small series R with the motor to limit startup current - BUT we need to know what you are really doing.

Comment: Ok, just added a schematics. When I say that I connect the boost convert directly to the motor is by connection to OUT1 and OUT2 directly. In this case, it works fine and at full speed.

Comment: Your "schematic" does not show any of the parts of the system which matter.  Anyway using a boost converter to drive a motor is almost always a bad idea.  Instead, use a motor suited to the battery type.

Comment: Hmmpf.  Never heard something be called a ["mung bean"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Mung%20Bean) before.

Comment: The boost converter has a maximum output of 30 watts.  At 10V output, that means a maximum of 3A to your motor, and it means about 8A from the battery.

Comment: But even if I lower it (the converter vout) to 5V, which is still ok (converter minimum is 4.5V) I get nothing...

Comment: Have you measured the output voltage of the boost converter when "nothing happens?"  Does it drop and stay low?

Comment: No, it stays the same.

Comment: If the output voltage of the booster stays constant but the motor doesn't turn, then there's something strange going on.  I'd suspect a mistake in the wiring somewhere.

Comment: Did you try a small series resistor wth motor as I suggested. "Nothing happens" MIGHT be a very rapid current spike and then overload cutout.

Comment: Yes, tried but no luck. Maybe @JRE is right and is something related to wiring. I double, triple checked everything and it seems ok. But at the same time, the full setup is quite a mess now, so I'll clean and re-wire everything.

Comment: @Miguel You have not provided a full diagram of what you THINK you are doing. The driver is full bridge so motor terminals need to be connected in isolation from Vin. || If you can drive the motor via controller from  say 3S Liion (9V - 12.6V range) but not from the converter at say 9V then something is wrong.